# DELETE FROM query with JOINs not working?

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following MySQL query, which I'm using with PHP (5.2).

```
DELETE t1.*, t3.* FROM 
            forum_posts AS t1,
            forum_topics AS t2,
            user_points AS t3
WHERE  t1.topic_id = t2.topic_id
       AND t2.deleted = 1
       AND t1.post_id = t3.id
       AND t3.type = 'post'
       AND t1.post_author = t3.profile_author
```

However it's not functioning how I'm intending it too (nothing happens!), let me explain:

What I intend the query to be doing is to delete all rows in the `forum_posts` table and/or (I'm saying "and/or" because it will depend if the rows even exist) delete all rows in the `user_points` table => [if the topic in which the post was created has been deleted (*for your info to avoid confusion it's really just "hidden"*, we determine this by checking if it equals `1`)].

I hope the query structure explains it self, the `topic_id` is mainly used to `JOIN` the the tables together.

The query runs fine (gives no MySQL or PHP errors, so I would assume the syntax is fine?), I've checked the DB and theres topics which exist which are deleted (the `deleted` column is set to `1`) and theirs post which exist aswell for those topics (so it's not the case that there is no data).

Appreciate all replies.

Comment: Try replacing the `DELETE` with a `SELECT` and see if you get the rows you want to delete.

Comment: @Vache, I've just tried that, and it return nothing, I then tried removing the user_points part and it returned the rows for the post, seeing as the points don't exist I think that's the problem, is their any way to check if it exists inside the query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a personal preference of always specifying the joins explicitly instead of lumping everything in the where clause. This also helps in visualizing where you might need a LEFT join.

```
DELETE forum_posts t1, user_points t3
    FROM forum_posts AS t1
    INNER JOIN forum_topics AS t2 ON t2.topic_id = t1.topic_id
    INNER JOIN user_points AS t3 ON t3.id = t1.post_id
        AND t3.profile_author = t1.post_author
        AND t3.type = 'post'
WHERE t2.deleted = 1
```

Now, based on your statement, I'd suggest changing the second INNER JOIN to a LEFT JOIN:

```
DELETE forum_posts t1, user_points t3
    FROM forum_posts AS t1
    INNER JOIN forum_topics AS t2 ON t2.topic_id = t1.topic_id
    LEFT JOIN user_points AS t3 ON t3.id = t1.post_id
        AND t3.profile_author = t1.post_author
        AND t3.type = 'post'
WHERE t2.deleted = 1
```

I hope that helps!